# Close pop up dialog called from method

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

When opening a pop up dialog after clicking the save button, the dialog box does not closed.

I know that I can add

```
<footer> 
<button name="save_item" string="Save" type="object" class="oe_highlight" />                 
<button string="Cancel" special="cancel" class="oe_highlight" />
</footer>
```

And add method `save_item` in the model that will return `True` and close the pop up dialog.

But if I click the item on the grid (one2many widget) it will pop up with the action buttons and my custom save/cancel buttons. So the buttons will get redundant.

```
@api.multi
def add_item(self):
    # for record in self:
    return {
        "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
        "name": "Add Item",
        "res_model": "quotation.line",
        "view_type": "form",
        "view_mode": "form",
        "view_id": self.env.ref("prescription.view_quotation_line_form",False).id,
        "target": "new",
        "flags": {"form": {"action_buttons": True}},
        "context": {
                "default_quotation_id": self.id,
                },
    }
```

Is there a way to close the dialog pop up after clicking the default action button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have understood you, but can't you just open your pop-up with `action_buttons` set to *False* to use only your own buttons?

```
@api.multi
def add_item(self):
    # for record in self:
    return {
        "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
        "name": "Add Item",
        "res_model": "quotation.line",
        "view_type": "form",
        "view_mode": "form",
        "view_id": self.env.ref("prescription.view_quotation_line_form",False).id,
        "target": "new",
        "flags": {"form": {"action_buttons": False}},
        "context": {
                "default_quotation_id": self.id,
                },
    }
```

This way users would only have the possibility to click on your buttons and you could close the pop-up in your `save_item` method.

**EDIT**

After reading your comments, I understand that you want to get rid of your own buttons when the record is being edited because in this case you see 4 buttons, the default ones and yours. And when creating you do not have this problem. I guess you have created your own *Add item* button and you do not allow users to use the default One2many *Add an element* button, or something like that. Try with this then

```
...
    <field name="id" invisible="1"/>
...
<footer attrs="{'invisible': [('id', '!=', False)]}">
    <button name="save_item" string="Save" type="object" class="oe_highlight" />                 
    <button string="Cancel" special="cancel" class="oe_highlight" />
</footer>
```

Comment: I could, but as I have explained in the question. If I put my custom save/cancel buttons when I click on the one2many widget to edit them, The dialog box will display both action buttons and my custom save/cancel buttons.

Comment: When adding items buttons will shows save/cancel. But when editing items buttons will shows both action buttons (save/discard) and (save/cancel), 4 buttons. The buttons are displayed on top of each other so it is very confusing to user,

Comment: Check my edit, not sure if that is what you are looking for.